# Accessing attachment file for meta-information

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

A rails3 application with Carrierwave and [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) is loading files.  However in an attempt to get meta-information out it is hitting Errno::ENOENT

The helper method

```
  def image
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(@document.production_file)
  end
```

is called in the view

```
<%= image['width'] %>
```

but the error is specified as

```
No such file or directory - /uploads/document/production_file/1/leader_pg_600.jpg
```

Yet

```
localhost:3000/uploads/document/production_file/1/leader_pg_600.jpg
```

does show the file, and is identical to

```
<%= @document.production_file_url %>
```

why is this routing apparently not being seen?

ImageMagick is installed and the application is running a resizing manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the wrong form of information...

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(@document.production_file)
```

is only a string.
Should read

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(@document.production_file.path)
```